# Warning : Assign object to a variable before exporting as module default

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using react-redux, and this is my root Reducer:

```
import Customers from "./customers/reducer";

export default {
  Customers
};
```

but I got this warning: Assign object to a variable before exporting as module default. How do I deal with it?

Comment: Shouldn't this be `export default Customers`?

Comment: Right now, I just import one module, but later I will import more modules. While I tried your suggestion. That works. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to re-export multiple things, then you likely want them as regular exports, not default ones.

Comment: @StevenSong If you import it only to export again (like an index.js collecting from othr files) you could do: `export { default as Customers} from "./customers/reducer"; `

Answer (score 11):

There are some solutions:

1- Disable the warning

```
import Customers from "./customers/reducer";

/* eslint import/no-anonymous-default-export: [2, {"allowObject": true}] */
export default {
    Customers
};
```

2- create a const then export it

```
import Customers from "./customers/reducer";
const aName = {
    Customers
};
export default aName;
```

Read [this descriptions](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-anonymous-default-export.md) For more information.